# REST API, get user role?

Tags: user-roles, rest-api

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve a user's roles from the API, but I haven't been able to sort it. Is this information not accessible by default?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is totally possible by registering your own rest field into the response.

Here's some documentation on modifying response data. 
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/

Here's how to add roles to the endpoint:

```
function get_user_roles($object, $field_name, $request) {
  return get_userdata($object['id'])->roles;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_field('user', 'roles', array(
    'get_callback' => 'get_user_roles',
    'update_callback' => null,
    'schema' => array(
      'type' => 'array'
    )
  ));
});
```

Specifically, what I'm doing is creating a function called `get_user_roles` that retrieves the user roles, then registering a 'roles' field in the response, and tell it that the data comes from that function.

I also ran into an issue of it not playing nice when the data returned an `array`, so I told the schema to expect it in the `schema` property of the array passed in `register_rest_field`

Answer (score 7):

You just need to pass the context parameter with a value of `edit` in your url:

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1?context=edit
```

According to the [WordPress REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#schema-roles), you have to pass the context=edit to make this attribute appear in the response. If you do not include `?context=edit` the `roles` attribute will not be shown.

Comment: FYI: You need to have an authenticated user in your request in order to display the details using the context.

Comment: This works when accessing users in Dashboard with user editing capability. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the short answer is you can't get there from here. While it's possible create users with a given role, there's no mechanism (via this interface) to retrieve a user's roles. If desired, one could extend the API to create a custom endpoint, but I will likely pursue a different route.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure it out and it looks like you can get a list of capabilities and user's role by adding **edit context** to your request. It's also possible to receive list of users by specifying **roles** in request.

Hope it helps.